# How do you check for undefined when using an expression as the property name of object in Typescript strict mode?

Tags: typescript, object, expression, strict

Consider the following code:

```js
type Props = 'foo' | 'bar';
type ParRec = Partial<Record<Props, string>>;

function doSomething (item: ParRec) {
  const props: Props[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
  return props.map((prop) => {
    if(item[prop]) {
      const result: string = item[prop];
      return { result };
    }
    return {};
  });
}
```

typescript complains with ts(2322) where `const result` is declared that `string | undefined is not assignable to type string`.

The conditional truthy check `if(item[prop])` *should* ensure that it is not undefined.

This seems to only be a problem when using an expression as the property name of `item`, as the following code has no problem:

```js
function doSomething (item: ParRec) {
  const props: Props[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
  return props.map((prop) => {
    if(item.foo) { // using item['foo'] also works fine
      const result: string = item.foo;
      return { result };
    }
    return {};
  });
}
```

I could understand if the object definition was more ambiguous, but I am using the same union type to define both the expression I am using as a property name, as well as the object type definition itself. Is there another way to ensure that `item[prop]` is not undefined I am not aware of for strict mode?

I am using typescript 4.8.4, and this code is made to simply describe the type error, not to represent any actual functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result of `item[prop]` to a variable and use the variable in the check

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigcgGYIZqAHywCMBDOTAbgChRJYKAlCAY3UbmAEsyAbADwtWCOABMB8JMgA0UZMDjcAdgHMAfOto1sAV2WseCZVDEIAyggC2EYAAsVqqAApuwCFYBcnYQEooAN40UFAiygpQYIgo3lIoANoAuhzxOHiYcpjklIm0IXC2unAmUdIAdFZkYM7OpWD%20aOqBNMEhocYRBci6fMAcbh7xdbmtIdzYzl09wP5BbW0FwEUmAVBTvVAAvnltm6NrhcWB262bvrSbUDRAA)

```
function doSomething (item: ParRec) {
  const props: Props[] = ['foo', 'bar'];
  return props.map((prop) => {
    const result = item[prop]; // string | undefined
    if(result) { // narrowed to string
      return { result };
    }
    return {};
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Do you have any insight though, into _why_ this has to be done, especially since it works when not using an expression?